# SPSS : syntax error involving RECODE command

Tags: statistics, spss

I have run the following command in SPSS. But It's showing error

```
STRING NSAL(A8).
IF(EDU>12 AND GENDER='M') RECODE SAL (0 THRU 75000='A') (75001 THRU HI='B') INTO NSAL.
EXECUTE.
```

Where have I done mistake?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @RowlandShaw THE ERROR MESSAGE IS : `>Error # 4382 in column 38.  Text: SAL 
>An equals sign was not found when expected after a target variable in a 
>COMPUTE command. 
>Execution of this command stops. 
    EXECUTE.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `IF` and `RECODE` together in one command. Try `DO IF` instead.

```
STRING NSAL (A8).

DO IF (EDU>12 AND GENDER='M').
RECODE SAL (0 THRU 75000='A') (75001 THRU HI='B') INTO NSAL.
END IF.

EXECUTE.
```